# Counting the number of digits before and after the decimal point in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I need to write a C program that will compare the number of digits before decimal point and after the decimal point and make sure they are equal.

How can I count how many powers of ten we have before and after the decimal point?

Here is what I have so far:

```
void main()
{
    is_equal(6757.658);   
}

INT is_equal(double x)
{
   int digits = 0;
   while (x) {
     x /= 10;
     digits++;
   }

   printf("%d ",digits);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Floating-point numbers don't work the way you think they do. It's not particularly meaningful to ask how many decimal digits there to the right of the decimal point, because floating-point numbers are base-2, not base-10.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but I'm quite sure you are assuming a decimal representation of floating point.  That assumption is probably false, the most common representations of FP are binary in nature and can't represent 0.1 exactly any more that a decimal representation can represent 1/3 exactly.

Comment: i dont understand - if the number user will enter is 12.22 why you say i cannot take 12 and 22 and put then inside integers and than to compare between them??

Comment: @Sveta26: you cannot do that because a float cannot contain the value 12.22 - at the point where the string the user entered is converted to float, there will be a rounding error and the actual value of the float will be something like 12.2199999997

Comment: Exactly 12.2200000000000006394884621840901672840118408203125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3rd try:

Count the number of "digits" before and after a "."

- Null is considered not equal to anything
- I did not test this code it might contain typos.

  ```
  int is_equal(char *buffer)
  {
    char *temp;
    int leftLen,rightLen;

    temp = strtok(buffer,".");
    if (temp == null) return false;

    leftLen = strlen(temp);

    temp = strtok(buffer,".");

    if (temp == null) return false;

    rightLen = strlen(temp);

    return (leftLen == rightLen);
  }
  ```

---

**Old stuff...**

There are going to be lots of problems here, a floating point (double) in C is not always accurate to 100%; If you perform multiplication or division.  If you multiply the digits will change.

The best way to solve this problem is to render the double to a string and then parse that string.

You can use sprintf to write the formatted double to a buffer.

OR

You can skip using a double all together and use a string to start with.

Thus building on Marcelo's answer:

Read the string from the user into a buffer called `buff`

Then parse it with a statement like `sscanf(buf, "%d.%d", &a, &b);`

buff is a `char *` or a `char []`, `a` and `b` are `int`.  You test by saying `a == b`

```
void main()
{
  is_equal("6757.658");   
}

int is_equal(char *x)
{
   int left,right;

   sscanf(x, "%d.%d", &left, &right);

   printf("Left digits: %d\n\r",left);
   printf("Right digits: %d\n\r",right);

   return (left == right);
}
```

Comment: To be clear: floating-point numbers are **always** accurate.  They just can't represent all real numbers.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - Point taken -- edited my wording to be clearer -- it is not "100% accurate" after an arithmetic operation.

Comment: user will enter 22.33 i just need to take each one of the 22 and 33 and put them inside integer - for this reason i need to know the number i need to multiple the 33 - in this case 100 in order to make it integer

Comment: @Sveta26 - Exactly -- use a string and the split function (tho C may not have a split function)

Comment: @hogan: typo there, the function you *probably* mean is `sprintf()` or even `snprintf()`

Comment: This won't work; the OP wants to know the **number** of digits.

Comment: Also, the function should take a `const char *`.

Comment: @Hogan: Even with log10, this won't work.  You can't distinguish between `"4.3"` and `"4.03"`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - This example answers the comment by the OP above: `i dont understand - if the number user will enter is 12.22 why you say i cannot take 12 and 22 and put then inside integers and than to compare between them??`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - very good point about `x.03`  The solution has to just parse the string.  (Which I don't want to write without a C compiler to test)

Comment: Is there a way to parse not using sscan? this is forbiiden too - only scanf and printf

Comment: 124.30 has to be equal to 124.3 - it flases in the code above

Answer (score 2):

You do not seem to know binary representation of double/float variables as @AProgrammer suggests.

Your job is impossible if you use float/double. You may use string for the job.

something like below.NOTE: it's just a hint and not a good style.

EDIT: disable `cout` since this is C

```
bool checkFloat(string); //the function checks whether the string have a float number format
void twoPart(string num)
{
    if (!checkFloat(num))
        return;
    int i = 0;
    int a = 0;//integer part
    int b = 0;//fractional part
    for(;i<num.length() && num[i]!='.'; i ++);
    a = i;
    b = num.length() - a - 1;
    if(i == num.length())
        b = 0;
    // print the result here
    //cout << a << " " << b << endl;
}
```

The above piece of code accepts number like **123**, **123.456**, **.123**

Comment: than how can i convert it to string - pull out what before and put inside integer and pull out what after point and put inside integer?

Comment: @Sveta26 once you store the **number** into a **double/float variable**, it loses some information. So try to store it as string and convert it into double/float if needed.

Comment: The << operator cannot take operands of type char* in C.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit tricky. IEEE floats can't represent most decimal fractions exactly. The number 6757.658 is represented as a binary decimal: 0x1a65a872b020c5×2<sup>-40</sup>, which is exactly 6757.6580000000003565219230949878692626953125 (I think). I.e., your number actually has 40 decimal places.

This simplest work-around is to format it using something like `sprintf(buf, "%.10g", x);`, then read the parts back using `int a, b; sscanf(buf, "%d.%d", &a, &b);`. Alternatively, you could start with `int b = 1e10*(x - floor(x))` and keep dividing b by 10 until it isn't a multiple of 10 (`while (b%10 == 0) b /= 10;`).

Comment: it is user input to begin with -- he should just read it in as a string and then do the sscanf

Comment: @Hogan: That isn't obvious from the question. As written, the OP's program holds the number as a literal, not as a string supplied via stdin or argv.

Comment: MY ACCURACY HAS TO BE 0.1-k+2

Comment: @Sveta26: Firstly, THERE'S NO NEED TO SHOUT. Secondly, huh?

Answer (score -5):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

float main(void)
{
    int siz;
    assert (sizeof siz == sizeof (float));

    siz = is_equal(6757.658);
    printf( "Size=%d\n", siz);

    return 0.0;
}

int is_equal(double x)
{
    int digits;
    for (digits=0; x >= 1.0; digits++) {
        x /= 10;
    }

    return digits;
}
```

Comment: To check the validity of main() s return type. Maybe the OP can explain it to his teacher?

Comment: Why not just do something sensible, like return an `int`?

Comment: I need int is_equal(double x)

Comment: It is wrong, just like "void main()" is wrong. But it is *less wrong* than "void main()". Given the assert, it should even compile and execute, since ints have no trap-representation.

Comment: @wildplasser: It's not less wrong.  Why not just modify your example to return an int?

Comment: do you have to use assert ? can you not use the assert ? i cant use assert in this prog PLEASE:)

Comment: Because I try to explain how very wrong "void main()" is. Lol@ "I cannot use assert()"

Comment: the function need to be int because if it is equal then it is 1 if the numbers are not equal then it 0

Comment: #include <assert.h> is forbidden
 in this project only matt.h and stdio.h

Comment: Of course I do, and I don't care. Can't we just have some lulz over a guy who posts the same silly question twice (the first one was deleted) **without** a homework tag? Now please go downvoting every "answer" with "void main()" in it.

Comment: Amen, brother! Let's fight them on the doubles, let's fight them on the float ;-)